# Why does this function return "None None" as well?

Tags: python, printing, return

*I've searched regarding this and came across list returning functions but I still don't understand it.*

I'm trying to understand why Print function to another function returns the following :

```
Happy Birthday
Happy Birthday
None None
```

My Code:

```
def happy():
    print("Happy Birthday")

def main():
    print(happy(), happy())

main()
```

I know that function returns special object called :None. But I'm just trying to understand why it does so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every function always returns a value.  If you don't explicitly return a value, and the function just gets all the way to the end, then it automatically returns None.  Your function `happy` doesn't have any `return` statement, so at the end of the function, it automatically returns None.

Comment: Does it return "NONE" after every function call? Or after print calls all of the functions then at the end prints the returned values of None?

Comment: The functions return `None` at the end of each call, but both None values are printed at once, because both calls are done before the `print` is actually done.

Comment: That answered it. Thank you. Understanding that print is not done, it is calling both functions before it can print the actual values (even if they are none) after function calls. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 3):

when you call to happy() returns none, so after each function is called you are printing

print(None, None)