# why does function print "none" when I have a return statement

Tags: python

I am trying to have my function return prices when the user selects what size they want

```
def CalculateTotal():
    strSize = input("Enter the size of tea (S)mall, (M)edium, (L)arge, (J)umbo: ")
    
    if strSize == S:
        price1 = "2.99"
        return price1
    elif strSize == M:
        price2 = "3.59"
        return price2
    elif strSize == L:
        price3 = "4.09"
        return price3
    elif strSize == J:
        price4 = "4.99"
        return price4
```

I have tried rearranging my code, the closest I've got was having it return all the prices at once

Comment: What are `S`, `M`, `L` and `J`? They're names (`S` compared to `"S"`), so they'd need to be defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: What happens if your `strSize` is neither S, M, L, or J? None of the return statements is executed, the end of the function is reached, and the return value is `None` by default.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Why does this function return "None None" as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189954/why-does-this-function-return-none-none-as-well) (@dawg), but the problem seems to have been caused by a basic logic mistake (like Robert said) and this code is incomplete (like AKX said), so I don't think it's worth reopening it. If the problem does go deeper, please make a [mre] and [edit] it in. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Consider using a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): `rtr=dict(zip('SMLJ',["2.99","3.59","4.09","4.99"]))`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing with variables (which may raise a `NameError` if they aren't defined) rather than strings.

```
def CalculateTotal():
    strSize = input("Enter the size of tea (S)mall, (M)edium, (L)arge, (J)umbo: ")
    
    if strSize == "S":
        price1 = "2.99"
        return price1
    elif strSize == "M":
        price2 = "3.59"
        return price2
    elif strSize == "L":
        price3 = "4.09"
        return price3
    elif strSize == "J":
        price4 = "4.99"
        return price4
```

Moreover, you have no `else`, so there is a path through your function with no explicit return, and thus the result would be `None`.